# PHP cURL: How do I make it visit this website before continuing?

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I am passing post data to a website, but I have to visit the homepage first before I can navigate to any other parts of the website. So how can I do that? Do I just use a header redirect and then have it execute the rest of the cURL?

Update:

I think this might be better than the solution below: http://coderscult.com/php/php-curl/2008/05/20/php-curl-cookies-example/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run two cURL calls using the same object. So first initialize cURL with the homepage URL, and execute the session:

```
$curl = curl_init("http://example.com");
curl_exec($curl);
```

Then using the same object, set a new URL, and execute it with your set parameters:

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,"your_new_url");
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"var1=value&var2=another_value");
curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: Actually you're right! The website stores cookies, how do I make sure this happens?

Comment: Well in that case, add **curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"your_cookies.txt");** before the first curl_exec(), and add **curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"your_cookies.txt");** before the second curl_exec(). That way the cookies from the homepage will be stored in the variable on the first run, and sent back to the server on the second run.